# HTML input range using 'onchange' to change a variable

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I wish to use a range slider to change the radius of a circle, however i can't manage to have the circle draw on the canvas when I use the variable changed with the range slider - Can anyone correct me where I've gone wrong?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='StylesheetSlider.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test Slider</h1>
        <p>Slider Options</p>
        <label for = "radius">Radius:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="range" onchange="this.setAttribute('value',this.value);" min="50" max="500" value="50" onchange = "changeRad(this.value);"/>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="5000" height="5000">
        </canvas>
        <script>
            function changeRad(r) {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(50, 50, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Adding the working code link
[Check Code here](https://jsbin.com/nupecox/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
  <h1>Test Slider</h1>
    <p>Slider Options</p>
    <label for = "radius">Radius:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="range" min="50" max="500" value="50" onchange = "sample(this.value); changeRad(this.value);"/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="5000" height="5000">
    </canvas>
    <script>
    function changeRad(r) {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(50, 50, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.closePath();
              console.log(r);
    }

    function sample(r){
      console.log("second function",r)
    }
    </script>
```

You have put two onchange events in the input tag. Removing the first one will make it work.

Comment: Is it possible to have both in one? As in maybe `onchange="this.setAttribute('value',this.value); changeRad(this.value);"`?

Comment: Yes it's possible.
https://jsbin.com/nupecox/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Much appreciated :D